# laminations and branched surfaces

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

I am looking for a reference for this question: given a branched surface in a 3-manifold, how we can construct a lamination fully carried by that branched surface.
any comments would be appreciated.

edit: maybe I should be more specific. I'm reading D.Gabai's paper "foliations and topology of 3-manifolds III" where he constructs finite depth laminations carried by branched surfaces as part of construction of finite depth foliations (the branched surfaces themselves are constructed using a sutured manifold decomposition), so branched surfaces don't seem to be weighted.

Comment: Do you just need a reference to cite or are you looking for a construction?

Comment: @DouglasZare I'm looking for a construction actually.

Comment: Are you familiar with one dimension lower, building a lamination carried by a train track? You want something analogous on the branch locus, with a similar compatibility condition.

Comment: but the train tracks are weighted and branched surfaces are not! actually I'm reading D.Gabai's paper named "foliations and the topology of 3-manifolds III" and in some part he constructs laminations carried by branched surfaces as part of construction of finite depth foliations. (which I couldn't understand the proof)

Comment: It's not even true that every branched surface $B$ fully carries a lamination. "Twisted discs of contact" are an obstruction; see the paper of Tao Li referenced in the answer of @user39082. So your question is not well-formulated.

Comment: @Lee Mosher: I was hoping you would find this question! I wanted to mention your result on the algorithmic undecideability of whether an abstract branched surface fully carries a lamination but I wasn't sure what reference to give, or the best current results for branched surfaces embedded in $3$-manifolds. Would you suggest any references for these? However, I suspected that the OP was looking for information on essential laminations fully carried by branched surfaces with extra conditions, though not necessarily what Tao Li considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tao Li https://www2.bc.edu/~taoli/lbs.pdf constructs an essential lamination for each branched surface satisfying the following conditions:

(1) Its horizontal boundary is incompressible; (2) there is no monogon; (3) there is no Reeb component; (4) there is no sink disk (after eliminating trivial bubbles in the branched surface).

The conditions are necessary except for laminations by planes.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think essential lamination is the right concept in the context I'm reading now. I'm reading D.Gabai's paper "foliations and topology of 3-manifolds III" , as part of construction of finite depth foliations, he constructs finite depth depth laminations carried by branched surfaces(and these branched surfaces themselves are constructed using the sutured manifolds decomposion), I think I should have written my question more accurate.

Comment: @ola: Actually Li's construction works perfectly well in the context of Gabai's paper, because all of the branched surfaces that Gabai constructs satisfy the hypotheses of Li's construction.